# Django: Import error when trying to use django-audiofield from GitHub

Tags: python, django, aptana

I'm trying to use a [django application on Github called django-audiofield](https://github.com/Star2Billing/django-audiofield) in my django project. I'm using Aptana Studio IDE. I installed it in my virtual environment and I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Aptana Studio 3.0/musicproject/src/manage.py",    line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 196, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 232, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/validate.py", line 9, in handle_noargs
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 266, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 30, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 158, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 67, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 88, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/models.py", line 19, in <module>
    from audiofield.fields import AudioField
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/fields.py", line 20, in <module>
    from tasks import audio_convert_task
    File "/Users/home/virtualenv/venv/src/audiofield/audiofield/tasks.py", line 14, in <module>
    from celery.task import Task
  ImportError: No module named celery.task
Finished "/Users/home/Desktop/Web Development/Aptana Studio 3.0/musicproject/src/manage.py validate" execution.
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the package, thanks to your post I realized that we were missing celery/django-celery in our requirements. It's now added in the latest version.

So "pip install django-audiofield" will install those dependencies for you.
If you have django-audiofield already installed you can run the following command to upgrade : "pip install django-audiofield --upgrade"

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed [celery](http://celeryproject.org/)? If no, install celery (`pip install celery`). If the github application in question (a link would have been nice) has a requirements.txt file anywhere, do `pip install -r requirements.txt` to install all the required dependencies of the application.

If yes, it looks like your [import search path](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/everything_is_an_object.html#d0e4550) may not be set up correctly to find Celery - just a guess based on the import error.

Open up the django shell (type `python manage.py shell` when you're in your project's working directory) and type in `import sys; print sys.path`. Make sure that Celery is installed in one of those directories, since [`sys.path`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.path) specifies the import search path for python modules.

If it isn't included there, you can temporarily append the directory celery is installed into by doing `sys.path.append("<directory where celery is>")` (mind the backslashes, since you're on Windows). If, after doing that, you can successfully `from celery.tasks import Task`, then you can set the [`PYTHONPATH`](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable appropriately to make it permanent.

Also, since you installed Celery into a [virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/), it may be worth checking that both django and Celery are in the same virtualenv.

Finally, the latest commits to Celery indicate [Celery now has native Django support](https://github.com/celery/celery/commit/04b0027e64e6b1ec6211ff67e86128c8fe1eeed4), but since that hasn't been released as a stable version yet, you may want to look at [`django-celery`](http://ask.github.com/django-celery/).

**Edit** (in response to comment below):

Since you mentioned you're trying to get [django-audiofield](https://github.com/Star2Billing/django-audiofield) to work: it seems to [be on pypi](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-audiofield). This means you can use pip (or easy_install) to install it using `pip install django-audiofield` once you've installed all the required (non-python) dependencies, and stuff like celery should be downloaded for you.

Comment: thanks a lot @Casper. I apologize for not including the link. here's the link: git://github.com/Star2Billing/django-audiofield.git

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks for the link; I've proposed an edit to your question to add it in there. Also, if this answer helped you solve the problem, please accept it by clicking the outline of the tick next to it!

Comment: thank you again. I did do a "pip install django-audiofield" and I'm not sure why celery didn't get downloaded. I guess I'll have to manually download it. thanks again @caspar